# What's the definition of the function analogous to ${\times}_m:R{\times}G{\rightarrow}G$ in a bimodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modules, bimodules

Let $g,g_i\,{\in}\,G$ and $r,r_i\,{\in}\,R$

If $(G,+_g)$ is an Abelian group and $(R,+_r,*_r)$ is a ring, then we call objects $(G,+_g,{\times}_m)$ left $R$-modules iff ${\times}_m:R{\times}G{\rightarrow}G$, ${\times}_m$ is distributive and associative, and right $R$-modules iff ${\times}_m:G{\times}R{\rightarrow}G$ with distributive and associative ${\times}_m$.

In left and right modules, $g{\times}_mr$ isn't simply not necessarily equal to $r{\times}_mg$ - in both cases, one of these is undefined, it doesn't exist.

The only exception is when $G=R$ and $+_G=+_R$, but I'm pretty sure there are bimodules other than ones in which these properties are met.

How is ${\times}_m$ defined in bimodules?

Are there simply two different functions, ${\times}_{m_L}$ and ${\times}_{m_R}$, instead of a single one like in left and right modules, or is there indeed a single ${\times}_m$ in bimodules?

Comment: As long as the ring is unital, you can just define the obvious map from $R\times G\times R$ to $G$.

Comment: What if it isn't unital? What would this map look like?

Comment: I haven't thought much about that. The issue is that you need to be able to act only from one side at a time, and there is not necessarily any element to plus into the remaining argument to achieve this.

Comment: So, for unital rings you can define an $(R,S)$-bimodule by a map $\phi:R\times G\times S\to G$ satisfying some axioms, or alternatively define it by maps $\alpha:R\times G\to G$ and $\beta:G\times S\to G$ satisfying some axioms. Can you figure what the axioms should be, and how to convert $\phi$ into $\alpha,\beta$ and vice-versa? For nonunital rings, as Tobias mentions, if you want to be able to multiply on one side at a time you'll need to use the definition with two maps $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: I think you should have two such functions with a compatibility condition, unless the ring is unital in which case what Tobias said

Comment: What's a compatibility condition? Google gives me only results related to mechanics and engineering.

Comment: It's a condition that expresses how mappings should be compatible with each other. For instance, if $\alpha:R\times G\to G$ is a left $R$-module structure and $\beta:G\times S\to G$ is a right $S$-module structure for which $\alpha,\beta$ make $G$ an $(R,S)$-bimodule, then $\alpha(r,\beta(g,s))=\beta(\alpha(r,g),s)$. Another term would be "coherence conditions."